# Unable to identify link class

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to Programming and Python and am trying out to code this simple scraper to extract all the profile URLs of therapists from this page

http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/search.php?search=Sheffield&services[23]=1&business_type[individual]=1&distance=40&uqs=626693

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def tru_crawler(max_pages):
   p = '&page='
   page = 1
   while page <= max_pages:
     url = 'http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/search.php?search=Sheffield&distance=40&services[23]=on&services=23&business_type[individual]=on&uqs=626693' + p + str(page)
     code = requests.get(url)
     text = code.text
     soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
     for link in soup.findAll('a',{'member-summary':'h2'}):
        href = 'http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk' + link.get('href')
        yield href + '\n'
        print(href)
    page += 1
```

Now when I am running this code, I am getting nothing, primarily because the soup.findall is empty.

The HTML of the profile link shows

```
<div class="member-summary">
<h2 class="">
 <a href="/therapists/julia-church?uqs=626693">Julia Church</a>
</h2>
```

So I am not sure what additional parameters to pass in soup.findall('a') in order to get the Profile URLs

Please help

Thanks

**Update -**

I ran the revised code and it returned a bunch of errors

Okay this time after it scraped page 1 it returned a bunch of errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PB/PycharmProjects/crawler/crawler-revised.py", line    19,      enter code here`in <module>
tru_crawler(3)
File "C:/Users/PB/PycharmProjects/crawler/crawler-revised.py", line 9, in tru_crawler
code = requests.get(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\api.py", line 68, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 464, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 602, in send
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 195, in resolve_redirects
allow_redirects=False,
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',  BadStatusLine("''",))
```

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, parameter of `findAll()` you have doesn't make sense. It reads: find all `<a>` having `member-class` attribute equals "h2".

One possible way is using `select()` method passing [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) as parameter :

```
for link in soup.select('div.member-summary h2 a'):
    href = 'http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk' + link.get('href')
    yield href + '\n'
    print(href)
```

Above CSS selector reads: find `<div>` tag having class equals "member-summary", then within that `<div>` find `<h2>` tag, then within that `<h2>` find `<a>` tag.

Working example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

p = '&page='
page = 1
url = 'http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/search.php?search=Sheffield&distance=40&services[23]=on&services=23&business_type[individual]=on&uqs=626693' + p + str(page)
code = requests.get(url)
text = code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
for link in soup.select('div.member-summary h2 a'):
    href = 'http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk' + link.get('href')
    print(href)
```

Output (trimmed, from total 26 links) :

```
http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/therapists/lesley-lister?uqs=626693
http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/therapists/fiona-jeffrey?uqs=626693
http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/therapists/ann-grant?uqs=626693
.....
.....
http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/therapists/jan-garbutt?uqs=626693
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't return anything :(

Comment: @pb_ng hmm.. worked for me (a bunch of links got printed). see updated answer for how I tried

Comment: Thanks, so removing the "yield href + '\n" makes it work. If you wouldn't mind me asking, why was it that when using Yield, it didn't return anything?

Comment: One more thing, I notice that the While loop isn't working. It doesn't go to Page 2 and fetch the links. How do I fix that?

Comment: Did that, still scrapes page 1 only. Could you please check? Many thanks!

Comment: worked for me, tested for scraping 3 pages: https://gist.github.com/har07/0c1d4302e2cf7db759a7

Comment: Please see my original post. I got a bunch of errors after it scraped page1. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Page 2 starts with the URL - http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/therapists/ros-elderkin?uqs=626693 which can't be found in the list of links scraped

Comment: @pb_ng seems you're right. Turned out that, using code in the gist link above, I got redirected to the first page over and over again (no error though). I'd suggest to open a new question as this is completely different problem form the one you originally asked.